# Error: cannot find symbol class/variable "TransportMediator"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm having an issue with my code when i try  to run the app these errors  shows  up but i really don't know how to solve this all the dependencies Update  tried to clean rebuild and validate chache but nothing  happened here is the gradle file and the project gradle of the app any help is appreciated

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amiapp.videodownloader"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/glide-3.6.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.turhanoz:reactivedirectorychooser:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.timqi.sectorprogressview:library:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.geniusforapp.fancydialog:FancyDialog:0.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`Error:(10, 32) error: cannot find symbol class TransportMediator`

`Error:(98, 31) error: cannot find symbol variable TransportMediator`

Comment: Will you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

TransportMediator can be found in the [v4 Support Library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/00ae8b5fd5c50d355b5cd2633d1b4729c8bd59f0/v4/java/android/support/v4/media/TransportMediator.java).

Include `'compile com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'` in your module-level build.gradle file.

Comment: add that  but still same issue
`mWebView.requestFocus(TransportMediator.KEYCODE_MEDIA_RECORD);
        mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });`